# expand column width to the size of the largest value in that column?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel if you double-click a column on its right "border" you can auto-size the width to be the width of the largest value in that column.

How does one replicate this in VBA?

Comment: Record a macro and see? (range.entirecolumn.autofit)

Comment: Apologies- completely forgot I could do that!!!

Comment: Post it as an answer and I will accept- I think you were first anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Macro Recorder to perform the action & see;

```
<range>.entirecolumn.autofit
```

Comment: + 1 for suggesting the Macro Recorder.

Answer (score 3):

Call the `AutoFit`Method of a `Column`object.

Like so:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

or like so:

```
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Same logic to Auto resize a row's height ;)